# Setting a cell to show last date the row was updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently setting up a column which will show the date a row was last updated. I have the following code which works fine but wondering if it can be refined slightly as it is a spreadsheet with lots of sheets:

```
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var row = range.getRow();

  if (sheetName == 'Data 150' || sheetName == 'Data 153')
  {
   var new_date = new Date();
   spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 26).setValue(new_date).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy"); 
  }

}
```

2 queries: a) currently this impacts row 1 which is a header row - is there an additional line I can add to get the script to ignore row 1 please? And b) Instead of setting up the different sheetNames as in the example above, can I set the if function to action this for any sheet that has "Data" in its name instead of matching the exact sheet name. All of my sheets have "Data" in the name but are followed by different numbers and so being able to do it this way would be a massive timesaver.

Edit: Just for clarity, this is for Google Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

In my understanding of your question, you want to:

1. Ignore the header *(row 1)* when running your script.
2. Run the update only to matching sheet names that contain *'Data'*.

Perhaps you can try this modified script below with [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method that uses **[regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions)** & [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) with [short-circuiting](https://medium.com/@ezekielphlat/a-simpler-understanding-of-the-short-circuit-operators-in-javascript-d275a313cef1) *(when you want to auto run a single script once condition are met)* :

***[UPDATED]***

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var row = range.getRow();

  //Catch & run if sheetName contains any 'Data' & ignore the header ('row 1')
  sheetName.match(/data/gi).length > 0 && row != 1 && spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 32).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  
}
```

---

### Demo

*Header on row **1** is ignored:*

[image]

*Script only processes sheet names with 'Data':*

[image]

*Other sheet names (without 'Data') will be excluded:*

[image]

Comment: @The_Train I hope this helps. If there's anything else missing, feel free to leave a comment. Have a good one!

Comment: Hi @SputnikDrunk2, thanks for this. Your demo's do exactly what I need but it doesn't seem to want to work in my sheet. The cell that the date shows has now changed to Column AF so I have amended the script to column 32 instead of 26 but getting on reaction from it, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Hi @The_Train. Would you mind sharing a dummy sheet with a similar structure to your current one for precise replication on my end?

Comment: Hi @SputnikDrunk2 - I have replicated my spreadsheet using 3 of the worksheets from it - data is not sensitive and I have set it for you to be able to edit

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKabBrLZoqu3AdsFFq5QPKF_sCNp_eqapvYsCd2AQAg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @The_Train I have updated the script on the answer. I apologise as it seems the `onEdit(e)` function is missing. Please try it again with the complete `onEdit(e)` function.

Comment: Thanks @SputnikDrunk2 - I did add an onEdit function but missed the (e) bit. At least my mind was on the right track though, maybe I am learning script after all :)

Thanks for amending, this now works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(o) {
  const sh = o.range.getSheet();
  const ns = ["Data 150", "Date 153"];
  const idx = ns.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if (~idx) {
    sh.getRange(o.range.rowStart, 26).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }
}
```